# How to pull survey questions from multiple survey records

Tags: lightning, survey, salesforce-survey

The way Salesforce Survey Builder is defined, you can create questions in the Builder and they will be tied to a Survey Version, and then tied to a Survey record.

If a user decides to create a new Survey, is it possible to retrieve Survey Questions that were created in different Survey records? Assuming the new Survey is NOT a version of an existing survey.

**Survey A is in Survey Version 1 and has Survey Questions 1, 2, and 3.
Survey B is in Survey Version 1 and has Survey Questions 4, 5, and 6.
How do I create a Survey C with Questions 1 and 6?**

Current approach: Create a new version of Survey A and manually create Question 6.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no other way than manually adding the questions you want in the new Survey you created.